# How to use onload in react?

Tags: reactjs

To run the imagesrore function onload I have to call `<img src="image_7.jpg" className="hide" alt="image_7.jpg"/>` image but actually there is no use of this line and if I remove this onload doesn't work and function is not called. So how can I call the imagestore() onload in react.

```
class PicturesList extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
          imagesarray: []
          };
          this.imagestore = this.imagestore.bind(this);
        }
        render() {
          return (
          <div>
            <div onLoad= {() => this.imagestore()}>
                <img src="image_7.jpg" className="hide" alt="image_7.jpg"/>
                // To run the imagesrore function onload I have to call this image but actually there is no use of this line and if I remove this onload doesn't work and function is not called
            </div>
            <Gallery url={this.state.imagesarray}/>
          </div>
          );
        }
        imagestore()
        {
        const imgUrls=this.props.apikeys;
        const objarr = Object.values(imgUrls);
        this.setState({
            imagesarray: objarr
        });
        }

      }
```

what I want

```
class PicturesList extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
              imagesarray: []
              };
              this.imagestore = this.imagestore.bind(this);
            }
            render() {
              return (
              <div>
                <div onLoad= {() => this.imagestore()}>

                    // but when I did this imagestore() function not called
                </div>
                <Gallery url={this.state.imagesarray}/>
              </div>
              );
            }
            imagestore()
            {
            const imgUrls=this.props.apikeys;
            const objarr = Object.values(imgUrls);
            this.setState({
                imagesarray: objarr
            });
            }

          }
```

Comment: try this once , componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('load', this.imagestore); // or this.imagestore()
 }

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of rendering the image which you dont want, you could simply load it in componentDidMount like

```
class PicturesList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
      imagesarray: []
      };
      this.imagestore = this.imagestore.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       const img = new Image();
        img.onload =() => {
          // image  has been loaded
          this.imagestore()
        };

        img.src = 'image_7.jpg';
    }
    render() {
       return (
          <div>
            </div>
            <Gallery url={this.state.imagesarray}/>
          </div>
       );
    }
    imagestore() {
        const imgUrls=this.props.apikeys;
        const objarr = Object.values(imgUrls);
        this.setState({
            imagesarray: objarr
        });
    }

}
```

The above solution is just to call imageStore once an image is loaded. However if what you intend is to call imageStore when the component has fully loaded,just trigger `this.imageStore()` in componentDidMount

```
class PicturesList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
      imagesarray: []
      };
      this.imagestore = this.imagestore.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.imagestore()
    }
    render() {
       return (
          <div>
            </div>
            <Gallery url={this.state.imagesarray}/>
          </div>
       );
    }
    imagestore() {
        const imgUrls=this.props.apikeys;
        const objarr = Object.values(imgUrls);
        this.setState({
            imagesarray: objarr
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/ayush88089/react/tree/test in the index.html file... @Shubham

Comment: @AyushSrivastava What do you want me to look at

Comment: I just uses `<img src="image_7.jpg" className="hide" alt="image_7.jpg"/>` to load the function `imagestore()` but  If I don't use it  the onload is not called why?? and how can call the onload function such that `imagestore()` function is called .. see **what I want** section @Shubham

Comment: The way you have coded it, onLoad is called when the image actually loads and if there is not image onLoad won't be called. if however you intend to call imageStore when the component has loaded then you can simply call this.imageStore() in componentDidMount method directly

Comment: `<Gallery url={this.state.imagesarray}/>` this is connected to many component and the problem is I am loading the image_7.jpg unnecessory as I told u in above comment...

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 10):

Use useEffect() in React. You would use it like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{

**INSERT CODE YOU WANT RUN ON LOAD HERE **

}, [])
```

Remember to import useEffect as well with
`import React, { useEffect } from 'react'`

Comment: As a newbie working with making changes to way too advanced code for my skill level, I would just like to thank you for including that import-comment. I've looked through many questions describing useEffect and useState, but none actually mentions that little tidbit.

Answer (score 0):

Your onLoad function should be used at the `<img>` tag, not the `<div/>`.

Comment: Please see my updated question:- actually I just want that onload imagestore() function called but to call it I have to use that img tag but I don't want to use and when I don't use the img function then `onLoad` not called!!!!  @Andus

Comment: In that case, Shubham Khatri gave a nice answer about this :)